Is there a way to search lines of text for specific words, select all lines the word is on, and copy them all
So if I have a list like
(1.The_CAT_and_the_DOG_are_friends.
2.The_CAT_is_named_Purr.
3.The_DOG_is_named_Bark.
4.It_is_raining_CATs_and_DOGs.)

so if I search for the word named only lines:
(2.The_CAT_is_named_Purr.
3.The_DOG_is_named_Bark.)

should be selected. Can this be done in notepad++ or any other programs?

You can (book)mark the lines. What is the ultimate goal you want to achieve?

I have a list of over 9000 lines that I want to filter out by the words on the line like my example so I don't have to look through it all. Thanks it was a lot easier then I thought.

The NppTextViz Plugin used to do an awesome job with this, with its "Show lines with clipboard text". But it has been crashing with the latest version of NPP https://github.com/KubaDee/NppTextViz/issues/6

The simplest method for this is using the Line Filter plugin (found in the Plugin Manager as Linefilter3).
You select the word and go to Plugins > Line Filter > Keep lines with selection:

It will open a new file just with the lines containing this word.

The built-in way in Notepad++ would be using the bookmark feature:

In the Search window, go to the Mark tab
Enter the search term, check Bookmark Line, then press Mark All

Then go to Search > Bookmark > Copy/Cut Bookmarked Lines
Paste it to a new file (or press Remove None-bookmarked Lines to have only them in the original file)

